# How to show specific content if data from 2 different tables match?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a problem with showing a user order information. I am using wordpress so ill have to use their functions. There is 1 table called forms which has all the order info that i want to show, and the other table called wp_users which has an email and username in it. The email will be the same as it is in forms so I was thinking of somehow trying to see if the email of forms and the email of wp_users match so then I can show that specific user his order information, but I have no idea how i would do that.

this is how i am getting the order and email info

```
$inputs = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM form WHERE md5(concat(ID)) =  '$validate'");
if (empty($_REQUEST) || !empty($_GET['order_nr'])) {


?>
<form name="abonnement" action="/"  method="post">
     1 jaar abonnement: <input type = "radio" name="option" value = "1" checked = "checked"><br>
     Eerst volgende nummer: <input type = "radio" name="option" value = "2"><br>
     Historische nummer <input type = "radio" name="option" value = "3">
    <br><br>
    Naam:<input type = "text" name="naam" value = "<?php echo $inputs->naam; ?>" required><br>

    Adres:<input type = "text" name="adres" value= "<?php echo $inputs->adres; ?>" required><br>
    Postcode/Woonplaats:<input type="text" name = "plaats" value = "<?php echo $inputs->plaats; ?>" required><br>
    Land:<input type= "text" name="land" value = "<?php echo $inputs->land; ?>"required><br>
    Telefoon: <input type = "text" name="tel" value = "<?php echo $inputs->telefoon; ?>"required><br>
    Email: <input type = "email" name="email" value = "<?php echo $inputs->email; ?>" required><br>
    Datum: <input type = "text" name="datum" value = "<?php echo $inputs->datum; ?>" required><br><br>
    <input type = "hidden" name="order_id" value = "<?php echo $inputs->ID; ?>"> 

    <input id = "appear" type = "checkbox" name ="cadeau"> Geeft u het abonnement cadeau? Vul dan ook het onderstaande formulier in.<br>
    <div id="cadeau">

    Naam:<input type = "text" name = "cadNaam">
    Adres:<input type = "text" name = "cadAdres"> 
    Postcode/Woonplaats:<input type = "text" name = "cadPlaats">
    Land:<input type= "text" name = "cadLand">
    Telefoon: <input type = "text" name = "cadTel" >
    Email: <input type = "text" name = "cadEmail"><br>
    </div>

    <input type = "submit" name = "formSubmit" value = "Verzenden"><br><br>
    </form>


   <?php
    $wpdb->insert( 'form', array( 
    'naam' => $_POST['naam'], 
    'adres' => $_POST['adres'],
    'plaats' => $_POST['plaats'],
    'land' => $_POST['land'],
    'telefoon' => $_POST['tel'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'datum' => $_POST['datum'],
    'cadNaam' => $_POST['cadNaam'], 
    'cadAdres' => $_POST['cadAdres'], 
    'cadPlaats' => $_POST['cadPlaats'], 
    'cadLand' => $_POST['cadLand'], 
    'cadTelefoon' => $_POST['cadTel'], 
    'cadEmail' => $_POST['cadEmail'],
    'option' => $option,
    'prijs' => $priceDB,
    'Tijd' => $now

));
```

And here is where i am creating the wordpress user

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$option = $_POST['option'];
$price = "";

if( null == username_exists( $email ) ) {
$password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
$user_id = wp_create_user( $email, $password, $email );

wp_update_user(
array(
  'ID'          =>    $user_id,
  'nickname'    =>    $email
)
);


$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->set_role( 'contributor' );

wp_mail( $email, 'Welcome!', 'Your Password: ' . $password );
}
```

So it would probably have to look something like this?

```
$orderinfo = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM form WHERE wp_users.email =       form.email");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query for retrive data of same email value.

```
 $orderinfo = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_user inner join form on wp_users.email = form.email");
```

If you want then check user id in wp_user and forms.

```
$orderinfo = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_user inner join form on wp_users.email = form.email and wp_user.user_id= form.user_id");
```

Comment: But how will i get the order info just for 1 user though? With this query it will show all the data from all users that matches email right?

Comment: Check that user id  in where condition that you want.